# DAX RANKX over 2 dimension columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to create a rank measure in a table over 2 dimension columns.  I am very new to DAX and all the examples of RANKX I see use just 1 dimension, eg, rank of sales by company name, or rank of sales by Location.  How would I get rank of sales by company name and location?

ie, given data in table [SalesData] as below:

```
CompanyName            Location           SalesVolume
Co1                    Boston               100
Co1                    New york             200  
Co2                    Washington           150
```

I want to rank company name / location combinations by sales volume, Co1 New York would be rank 1st, Co2 Boston would be 2nd, Co1 New York would be 3rd.

I tried this DAX:

```
Sales Rank = 
IF (
    ISFILTERED ('SalesData'),
    RANKX (ALLSELECTED('SalesData'), [SalesVolume],,ASC,Dense),
    0
)
```

Should that calculate the correct rank automatically based on whatever columns have been added to the visual (eg a table in power bi)?  ie, If my visual only has CompanyName, the rank will be by CompanyName.  If the visual has CompanyName and Location, the rank will be accross both those columns.

Or, do I need to specify which dimension columns I am ranking by in the DAX somehow?  If I use the DAX above and add multiple dimension columns it gives incorrect ranks, it only works correctly with one dimension column in the visual.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: In your question: `Co1 New York would be rank 1st, Co2 Boston would be 2nd, Co1 New York would be 3rd`. looks incorrect I guess. Please correct it

Answer (score 0):

see below if it's your need:
[image]

setp1. create sales measure

```
sales = sum([SalesVolume])
```

step2. create rank measure

```
rank = rankx(ALL('SalesData'),[sales],[sales],DESC)
```

*note that both of them are measures not columns.*